# javascript getDay() year from today for setting a cookie

Tags: javascript, date, cookies

I want to set a [cookie](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470821/So-You-Want-To-Set-A-Cookie-Huh.htm) in JavaScript using this,

`document.cookie=cookie_name+"="+YouEntered+"; expires=Saturday, 04-Apr-2015 05:00:00 GMT";`

and I noticed it requires an expiration date (with the day of the week) sometime in the future. I found that `getDay()` retrieves the current day of the week for today's date but is there a way to set the date to a future date in JavaScript and get the day of the week from that future date?

Comment: `someDateObject.setFullYear(someDateObject.getFullYear()+1)`

Comment: Tried that but it returns 1423865040509.

Comment: Well you of course have to _format_ it afterwards … `toGMTString`

Comment: Thanks I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<title>JavaScript Get Date</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var currentTime = new Date();            
        var year = currentTime.setFullYear(currentTime.getFullYear()+1);

    document.write(currentTime.toUTCString(year));
</SCRIPT>
<style type = "text/css">
body
{
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```